# Google analytics in SPA

Tags: hash, google-analytics, single-page-application

I have a website which is like this

```
http://domain/?key=32dxzQW
```

where the key is auto generated from other site per user

What I need to know are the sections most visited, so I was thinking in use GA, and as my webpage is SPA the sections are handled using hash (#) in the URL. Here some examples:

```
http://domain/?key=32dxzQW#start
http://domain/?key=32dxzQW#section1
http://domain/?key=sfd2ACS#start
http://domain/?key=sfd2ACS#section1
http://domain/?key=sfd2ACS#section2
http://domain/?key=ssC56tE#start
```

I want to know if there is a way to get by GA a summary of the sections, like this:

```
start       3
section1    2
section2    1
```

Help please

Update:
I already did the change to handle fragments and works:

```
    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
    function sendToGA() {
        ga('create', 'XXXXXXXXXXX', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview', {
            'page': location.pathname + location.search + location.hash
        });
    }
    sendToGA();
    window.onhashchange = sendToGA;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that came to my mind is to add click or other events on the sections you want to track and check them in the Behavior -> Events section in GA.

Comment: Just a thought: what if the user doesn't actually "click" into a section, and just scrolls through?

Comment: in my website there is no scroll, so thats not a problem

Answer (score 2):

GA doesn't track hashes (URL fragments) by default, but you can follow this guide to help with setting up virtual page views for each section of your page:

[Tracking URL page fragments](http://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/track-url-fragments-as-pageviews/)

Comment: OK, if it's working, then you should, in about 24 hours, see the virtual pages in your pages reports. Are they other issues you are facing?

Comment: well, your comment is valid but what i want was a summary of the sections most visited, and llyubcho's answer really help me, thanks anyway

Comment: No prob! I just thought you were doing scroll tracking.